# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client error is showing

Tags: node.js, express

**Error is showing if a user is already exiting. The error is not showing if the user does not exist in the database**
**Plz tell me if there is any better way to check the username thank you in advance**

```
exports.updateUser = async(req, res) => {
        if (req.body.userId === req.params.id) {
            if (req.body.userName || req.body.email) {
                await User.findOne({
                    $or: [{
                        email: req.body.email
                    }, {
                        username: req.body.userName
                    }]
                }).exec((err, user) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).json(err);
                    } else if (user) {
                        if (user.username === req.body.userName) {
                            return res.status(400).json({ error: "User Name already exists" });
                            //err = "User Name already exists";
                        } else {
                            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Email already exists" });
                        }
    
                    }
                })
    
            }
            if (req.body.password) {
                const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
                req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
            }
            await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
                req.params.id, { $set: req.body }, { new: true }
            ).exec((err, user) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).json(err);
                }
                if (user) {
                    return res.status(200).json("User Updated successfully!"); // here error is showing.
                }
            });
    
    
        } else {
            res.status(401).json("You can update only your account!");
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't send response inside exec, because if after sending response it'll execute rest of the code and try to send a response but response is already sent.

```
exports.updateUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.body.userId === req.params.id) {
      if (req.body.userName || req.body.email) {
        await User.findOne({
          $or: [
            {
              email: req.body.email,
            },
            {
              username: req.body.userName,
            },
          ],
        }).exec((err, user) => {
          if (err) {
            throw {
              code: 400,
              error: err,
            };
          } else if (user) {
            if (user.username === req.body.userName) {
              throw {
                code: 400,
                error: { error: "User Name already exists" },
              };
            }
            throw {
              code: 400,
              error: "Email already exists",
            };
          }
        });
      }
      if (req.body.password) {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
      }
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,
        { $set: req.body },
        { new: true }
      ).exec((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          throw {
            code: 500,
            error: err,
          };
        }
        if (user) {
          return res.status(200).json("User Updated successfully!"); // here error is showing.
        }
      });
    } else {
      throw {
        code: 401,
        error: "You can update only your account!",
      };
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(e.code).json(e.error);
  }
};
```

Comment: above code is not working, my node server is getting crashed. Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({ code: 400, error: { error: 'User Name already exists' } }). sir want to display the error client-side but I am not getting it in the response at client side in your given code. Sir, I am a beginner so plz help me.

Comment: above code is not working, my nodemon server is getting crashed. Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({ code: 400, error: { error: 'User Name already exists' } }). sir want to display the error client-side but I am not getting it in the response at client side in your given code. Sir, I am a beginner so plz help me.